# I want to get the latest value of input type Number And then pass it to the dispatch function but setState takes some time to update ? Details Below

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend

I want to get the latest value from the input element and for that i am controlling the element state using useState and also At the time of onchange event i want to fire a dispatch method which will Add increase the no of cart elements inside cart(whose logic is written in reducer)
Probleme is the fn returned by useState takes some time to update but i need to pass the updated value into the dispatch method like this
props.increaseCount(e.target.value)
so if i call the fn returned by useState before it takes some time and the previous value gets passed on the method which is dispatching an action .
How can I overcome this
.Code is shared below ?

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {
    TextField, makeStyles, Grid, Button, Paper, Card,
    CardContent, CardActions, Container, CardMedia,
    Typography,
    Box
} from '@material-ui/core';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import { InputLabel } from '@material-ui/core';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { removeItem } from '../store/actions/productAction';
import {increaseCount} from '../store/actions/productAction';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=>{
    return{
       mainDiv:{
           height:'100vh',
           width:'100vw',
           display:'flex',
        //    border:'3px solid black',
           position:'relative'   
        //    justifyContent:'center',
        //    alignItems:'center'
       },
    //    alignCenter:{
    //        justifyContent:"center"
    //    },
       image: {
        height: "15rem",
        backgroundSize: "cover"
    },
    textAlign:{
        textAlign:'center'
    },
    positionGrid:{
      position:'absolute',
      top:'2.5rem',
      left:'1rem'
    },
    boxDimensions:{
        display:'block',
        width:'65vw'
    },
    productBoxDimension:{
       display:'block',
       width:'65vw'
    },
    styleCard:{
        display:'flex'
    },
    mediaDiv:{
        height:'100%',
        width:'30%',
        
    },
    contentDiv:{
        height:'100%',
        width:'70%',
       
    },
    centerELements:{
        display:'flex',
        flexDirection:'row'
    }
    
    }
})
const Cart = ({cart,removeItem}) => {

    const [number,setNumber] = useState(1);
    // console.log(cart);
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.mainDiv}>
           <Container className={classes.positionGrid}>
               <Grid container className ={classes.alignCenter}>
                    <Grid item md={9}>
                      <Container>
                          <Grid container >
                             <Grid item={12}>
                                 <Box className={classes.boxDimensions}>
                                        <Card variant="outlined" width={1} height={1}>

                                            <CardContent >
                                                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6" component="h2" >
                                                    Shopping Cart
                                                </Typography>

                                            </CardContent>

                                        </Card>
                                 </Box>
                                   
                             </Grid>
                             {cart.map(item=>{

                                 return (
                                    <Grid item={12} key={item.id}>
                                      
                                      <Box className={classes.productBoxDimension}>
                                               <Card variant="outlined" width={1} className={classes.styleCard}>
                                                        
                                                   <div className={classes.mediaDiv}>
                                                       <CardMedia
                                                           image={item.image}
                                                           title="Paella dish"
                                                           className={classes.image}
                                                       />
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div className={classes.contentDiv}>
                                                       <Card variant="outlined"  style={{ border: "none", boxShadow: "none" }}>
                                                            
                                                           <CardContent >
                                                               <Typography gutterBottom color="primary" variant="h6" component="h2" >
                                                                   {item.title}
                                                               </Typography>
                                                               <FormControl>
                                                                   <InputLabel htmlFor="quantity">Qty</InputLabel>
                                                                   <Input id="quantity" type="number" value={number} 
                                                                    onChange={(e)=>
                                                                        setNumber(e.target.value)
                                                                       // here i want to fire the dispatch method and pass the latest valy=ue of number into it 
                                                                       //How Should i do it ????
                                                                        props.increaseCount(number);
                                                                    }
                                                                    name="quantity" inputProps={{min:1,max:5}}></Input>
                                                               </FormControl>
                                                               <Typography variant="subtitle2" color="t" component="p">
                                                                   {item.description}
                                                               </Typography>
                                                           </CardContent>
                                                           <CardActions className={classes.centerELements}>
                                                               <Button variant="contained" color="secondary"onClick={()=>removeItem(item.id)}>
                                                                   Delete
                                                               </Button>
                                                               <Typography color="textPrimary" variant="h6" component="h2" >
                                                                  {item.price}
                                                               </Typography>
                                                           </CardActions>
       
                                                       </Card>
                                                   </div>
       
                                               </Card>
                                        </Box>
                                    </Grid>
                                   
                                 )
                             })}
                        
                          </Grid>
                      </Container>
                       
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item md={2}>
                       Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi alias labore enim rem illo. Magnam pariatur ab architecto totam ratione? Neque deserunt quisquam tenetur dolorem minima nobis architecto magnam sint.
                    </Grid>
                   
                </Grid>
           </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
       cart:state.cartProducts
   }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        removeItem:(id)=>dispatch(removeItem(id)),
        increaseCount:(val)=>dispatch(increaseCount(val))
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Cart)
```

See Inside formControl component and then Input .
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `e.target.value` to `increaseCount` instead of `number`

```
props.increaseCount(e.target.value);
```

Comment: Will it work as I want to first click on the input type and increase the value and then I want to fire props.increaseCount with the increased value inside it ??